# Design time crash while using programmatic constraints and @IBDesignable

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, constraints, ibdesignable

I've been spinning my wheels for a couple days on this.  I can't find any demonstrations of programmatic constraints with `@IBDesignable`.

1. If I try `imgv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.  Then an apparent infinite loop is set and I literally have to quit Xcode, reopen it and quickly delete it before design time occurs.
2. As it is currently written, I have constraints that should change the imgv size to 200 width and height, but changing the values to 300 has no effect on the storyboard.  So It is as if the constraints have no effect.

**QUESTION:** How can I create programmatic constraints which would display on storyboard using `@IBDesignable?`## Heading ##

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class tryTVCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        setProperties()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setProperties()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setProperties()
    }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setProperties()
    }

    func setProperties() {
        backgroundColor = .blue
        let imgv = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 50, height: 50))
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let img = UIImage(named: "mountain", in: bundle, compatibleWith: traitCollection)
        assert(img != nil)
        imgv.image = img
        imgv.backgroundColor = .green
        let lab = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 10, width: 300, height: 300))
        lab.text = "hkjlkjlkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;lkj;l;lkjk;j;i"
        addSubview(imgv)
        addSubview(lab)


        imgv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        imgv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        imgv.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Comment: go to this path  `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` and search file name `IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch_*.crash` , add in you'r question `Thread Crashed`

Comment: Thank you.  I saw that from a similar question.  There was no crash in the DiagnosticReports directory.  :(  It seems to be stalling more than crashing.

Comment: The problem you have in this line `let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let img = UIImage(named: "mountain", in: bundle, compatibleWith: traitCollection)` is to use  `UIImage(named:"mountain")` from assets

Comment: Oh weird.  That part wasn't an issue.  However when I add translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false it suddenly works (leaving the image in or out). Should I delete this question?

Comment: Do not delete it, but put the correct answer and put the check green mark :)

Comment: @a.masri, you should post the answer since you've fixed OP's problem (and get the rep for it!)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth He says he solved the problem and I told him to add the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try adding again

```
 imgv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

after

```
addSubview(lab)
```

before

```
imgv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

It should work.